# Android MVVM ClickListener best practice

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, onclicklistener

As I read sunflower and many projects we have the multi clean ways for implementing a ClickListener

1. Binding clicklistener in view (Activity/fragment)
2. Creating a separated variable for clickListener on XML and call it on the constructor
3. Creating a static method and calling it from XML
4. Creating a viewModel with two uses (model and method) and passing the ViewModel class directly to XML and calling the method on our object

1

```
        binding.addPlant.setOnClickListener {
        navigateToPlantListPage()
    }
```

2

```
    <data>
    <variable
        name="clickListener"
        type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>
    <variable
        name="plant"
        type="com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.data.Plant"/>
</data>
```

then

```
        init {
        binding.setClickListener { view ->
            binding.viewModel?.plantId?.let { plantId ->
                navigateToPlant(plantId, view)
            }
        }
    }
```

3

```
    companion object{
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("bind:setSubjectText")
    fun setSubjectText(textView: TextView, string: String){
        val mTxt = "Subject: ${string}"
        textView.text = mTxt
    }
}
```

4

```
    <data>

    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.android.example.livedatabuilder.LiveDataViewModel" />
</data>
```

as a model

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_weather"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{viewmodel.currentWeather}"
        tools:text="Tokyo" />
```

in the same XML as a ViewModel method

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.onRefresh()}"
        android:text="@string/refresh_label" />
```

As you see each of them has some pros and cons. For instance for each theme:

1. Messy view
2. When we want to call multi-object in XML, the XML will be messy
3. In the large-scale program, we will engage with many static methods
4. Messy ViewModel

Question: which of them is the best practice for implementing clicklistener, especially in large-scale programs with some fragments by many clickable objects?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, none of the methods you mentioned were not good anymore, and any new project could use Jetpack Compose. In this fashion, you do not need fragments, XMLs, binding. etc

Comment: I know. It's true but migrating to Jetpack Compose is impossible for old large-scale programs. It's very expensive to write all the XML again by Compose. As a result, I'm searching for a way for the classic method.